# sudzc soap client deserialization error

Tags: ios, soap, sudzc

I'm using sudzc soap client in an iOS app.

Here is soap method declaration

`(SoapRequest*) UploadData: (myid <SoapDelegate>) handler myid: (NSString*) myid props: (NSString*) props`

For example, if i pass string "<test>" in the second parameter, i get following error:

> a:DeserializationFailed The formatter threw an exception while trying
>   to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request
>   message for operation 'UploadData'. End element 'props' from namespace
>   'http://tempuri.org/' expected. Found element 'test' from namespace
>   'http://tempuri.org/'. Line 1, position 338.

Why can't sudzc handle "<" or ">" characters in string parameter? Do i have to manually escape these characters?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this error is related to iOS or sudzc generator. SOAP uses XML for data transfer, so you have to encode any special characters according to [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/). See the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898259/whats-all-about-escaping-characters-in-xml).

Comment: My understanding is that soap internally escapes all the special characters. You mean to say, string parameter can't have < or > char?

Comment: SOAP is not a library, it's just a standard, based on XML. Thus, if library (sudzc in your case) supports character escaping, it escapes them. Otherwise you should take care of escaping.

Comment: i know what SOAP is. You are not answering my question though.

Comment: Answering your question - string parameter can have < or > chars, but they have to be encoded.